# How to give password-controlled access to a private GitHub repository?

Tags: github

Say I have:
(1) a FREE private repository (e.g.: associated with a non-open source publication), and
(2) shared some password/key in the publication, for the people purchasing it (NOT collaborators)
to use for accessing the repository (No collaboration! READ-ONLY rights)

- is that possible using GitHub? if yes, how?
  Otherwise:
- any alternatives to GitHub? (e.g.: GitLab, else?)

OR

- any alternative ways achieving the same limited-access, still using GitHub?

Thanks!

Searched for an answer, including GitHub Docs,and could not find one.

Comment: Typically you would edit the repository settings, go to the Collaborators and Teams submenu, and then invite anyone you want, giving them read-only access.

Comment: Thanks! however, the case of interest is that whoever buys the non-open source publication (say tens or hundreds of people), should use the password/key given in the publication to access the associated repo. That is: avoiding manually invite one-by-one, upon a prior request by some means.